# Java coin toss (Scanner, string processing,increment operator and arithmetic only)

Tags: java

I am working on a class project that involves writing a coin toss game that will print out statistics for eight coin tosses.

Here is a brief description:

The user will input either an “h” for heads or a “t” for tails for the eight tosses.The program will then print out the total number and percentages of heads and tails. Use the increment operator to increment the number of tosses as each toss.

Without using loops, ifs, fors, etc. I decided the closest solution to this problem was to use a combination of a string method like comparteTo() and maybe a formula to alter the incremented values for the results outputted.

My first problem is dealing with the strange outputs when using compareTo(), i.e.,
when I call "h" or "t"  per coin toss I will get a 0 for "h" and -12 for "t".

My question is how do I use compareTo() and arithmetic to get the total of heads and tails?

// assume scanner, headers ,etc

```
    String coin;
    int z,x;


    System.out.println("For each coin toss enter either 'h' for heads or 't' for tails.");

    System.out.print("First Toss:");
    coin = keyboard.nextLine();
    x = coin.compareTo("h");//heads
    z = coin.compareTo("t");// tails

    x = ++x;  // if user inputs "h" returns 0 for heads and -12  ???
    z = ++z;  // if user inputs "t" returns 12 for heads and 0 for tails ??? 

    System.out.print("Second Toss:");
    toss = keyboard.nextLine();

    x = coin.compareTo("h");
    z = coin.compareTo("t");

    x = ++x+x; // if user inputs "h" returns 2 for heads and -22 for tails 
    z = ++z+z; // if user inputs "t" returns 26 for heads and 2 for tails
               // if user inputs "t" for both tosses returns 26 heads and 2 tails ????

    //Omitted con tosses 3 through 8 for demonstration.


    System.out.println("Number of heads:" + x);
    System.out.println("Number of tails:"+ z);
    System.out.println("Percent of heads: (x/8.0))");  
    System.out.println("Percent of tails:"+ (z/8.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo` in string compare 2 strings lexographically [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)). It is ideally used for sorting within a category of collections which sorts individual elements added to it. The return value helps in identifying where the individual elements should be stored so that all the elements within the collection are stored in sorted format. Best example being in TreeSet or TreeMap.

When you compare string `"t"` with `"h"` since the difference in the number of alphabets between them is 12 it returns a value of 12.

You can instead use `coin.equalsIgnoreCase("h") // heads` and same with tails

Answer (score 0):

Okay, `so compareTo()` is not that good an approach. `equalsIgnoreCase()` is much better, and because it returns boolean, it can easily be converted to an int:

```
System.out.print("First Toss:");
coin = keyboard.nextLine();
x += coin.equalsIgnoreCase("h") ? 1 : 0;
z += coin.equalsIgnoreCase("t") ? 1 : 0;
```

Basically just repeating that above code snippet will give you exactly what you want, and work with your  output:

```
System.out.println("Number of heads:" + x);
System.out.println("Number of tails:"+ z);
System.out.println("Percent of heads: " + (x/2.0));  
System.out.println("Percent of tails:" + (z/2.0));
```